# How to test Material-UI's Responsive UI (e.g. Hidden, Grid, Breakpoints) in React with Enzyme or React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, enzyme, react-testing-library

How to test responsive elements in Material-UI?

Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import Hidden from "@material-ui/core/Hidden";

const HideOnMobile = (props) => {
  return <Hidden xsDown>{props.children}</Hidden>;
};
```

Test cases:

```js
describe(HideOnMobile, () => {
  describe("when screensize is sm", () => {
    it("shows children", () => {});
  });

  describe("when screensize is xs", () => {
    it("hides children", () => {});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MUI v5

Unfortunately, the [v4 solution doesn't work for v5](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2179#issuecomment-938249468).

MUI v4

As explained [here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2179#issuecomment-529320192) you can use theme props to set size properties for MUI:

```js
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const SizeWrapper = (props) => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    props: { MuiWithWidth: { initialWidth: "sm" } },
  });

  return <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>{props.children}</MuiThemeProvider>;
};
```

For example using React Testing Library:

```js
describe(HideOnMobile, () => {
  describe("when screensize is sm", () => {
    it("shows children", () => {
      const testMessage = "Test Message";
      render(<HideOnMobile>{testMessage}</HideOnMobile>, { wrapper: SizeWrapper });

      expect(screen.getByText(testMessage)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How would this work with breakpoints as the original question asked? I have a component that has an element given `display: none` at a certain breakpoint but when testing it with this method the styling doesn't update.

Comment: If you render it with the correct `initialWidth` it should have the right property. If you mean changing the size as part of the test I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it works with the Hidden component as the question states. You could also edit SizeWrapper to have a width parameter so the wrapper was more re-usable: { wrapper: (props) => SizeWrapper(props, 'xs') } for example

Comment: Thank you! Finally led me on a path to a working answer! Highly recommend reviewing the documentation now on how to handle [themeProviders](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render).  This works even when offsetWidth and innerWidth are not set.

Comment: Undervalued answer to an undervalued question.

Comment: A similar solution to I think the same underlying problem is mentioned [here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2179#issuecomment-529320192), unfortunately as of MUI v5 this is no longer possible since the `withWidth` (`MUIWithWidth`) has been removed from `createTheme` which replaces `createMuiTheme`. Currently our only working solution seemed to be to move away from `Hidden` components entirely as described in the [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#hidden).