# Simulate Width to Test Responsive React Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

There is a `Drawer` and a `Button` which opens the `Drawer`. The `Button` and the `Drawer` only appear in the DOM when the window width is less than 600.

This is the `Drawer` and `Button` code.

```
<Hidden smUp>
  <Button
    className={classes.button}
    variant="outlined"
    color="secondary"
    endIcon={<Menu />}
    onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}
    data-testid="DrawerMenuButton"
  >
    Menu
  </Button>
  <SwipeableDrawer
    anchor="left"
    open={open}
    onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}
    onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
    disableDiscovery
    data-testid="Drawer"
  >
    <div className={classes.list}>
      <List data-testid="DrawerMenuList">
        {drawerItems.map(({ icon: Icon, label, onClick }, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} button {...{ onClick }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Icon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={label} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  </SwipeableDrawer>
</Hidden>
```

When running `screen.debug()` during tests, this is the output

```
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

meaning that the width is not within the range for the components to appear.

How can the right width be set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test Material-UI's Responsive UI (e.g. Hidden, Grid, Breakpoints) in React with Enzyme or React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116406/how-to-test-material-uis-responsive-ui-e-g-hidden-grid-breakpoints-in-reac)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal you have the component  wrappig your children (drawer) so it will no be render to more than 600px

You can create media queries with [css media queries system](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries) this and get rid of hidden if you want

also there is a example if you want to see a bit of code in action an have an idea of what you have to do with yours with this you would be able to set any width to your drawer for any breakpoints :

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import {
  Drawer, Toolbar, List, Typography, ListItem, ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText, Box, IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core"
import clsx from "clsx"

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawer: {
    width: theme.sidebar.width,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
      top: "unset",
    },
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: theme.sidebar.width,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    },
  },
  expandButton: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(-2.5),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2.5),
    },
  },
  divider: {
    border: "1px solid",
    borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    margin: `0 ${theme.spacing(2)}px`,
  },
}))

export default function Sidebar(props) {

  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
       ...
  )
}
```